# Сложная формула с условием

Tags: excel

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как составить формулу для выполнения условия: если значение ячейки больше на 10 значения ячейки выше и ниже исходной, то результат равен А, иначе - D

Comment: пока ждал ответа, добрые люди подсказали такое еще решение:
=И(ИЛИ(ABS(RC[-8]-R[-1]C[-8])>10);ИЛИ(ABS(RC[-8]-R[1]C[-8])>10))

Answer (score 1):

Ваше условие будет цикличным, поэтому проявил немного вольности, и сравнил ячейку справа с ячейками сверху и снизу от испытуемой

```
=ЕСЛИ( И(RC[1]-R[-1]C[1]=10; RC[1]-R[1]C[1]=10); "A"; "D")
```